# Clearcase trigger: locked vs obsolete

Tags: clearcase

According to IBM technote [21468084](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21368084), a trigger should be unlocked to operate are locked (obsolete) to be disabled.

The ClearCase help for [lock](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm) also says:
In general, locking a trigger type does not inhibit triggers of that type from firing. Exception: Trigger firing is inhibited if a trigger type created with mktrtype –element  –all, mktrtype –ucm –all or if mktrtype –type is made obsolete (using lock –obsolete).

But a trigger can be in state "locked", not "obsolete". Is the "locked" behaviour then the same as "unlocked" unless actually "obsolete" ?

ps: if so, you'd think they would disallow setting locked !

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the "locked" behaviour then the same as "unlocked" unless actually "obsolete" ?

No. That behavior only applies to trigger *types*. Not trigger themselves.

> if a trigger is only disabled when the type it is in (obsolete ) state, is there a difference between being locked or unlocked ?

The difference is only that in a locked trigger (trigger, not trtype), it cannot be changed by anyone (it is locked).
That differs from it being able to fire or not, which depends on the trigger type state.

Comment: Apologies for the loose wording and lack of clarity. I guess what I meant to clarify was if a trigger is only disabled when the type it is in (obsolete ) state, is there a difference between being locked or unlocked ? The trigger would be "enabled" in either case.